# Significance of the name "Lorien"

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, names, babylon-5

In B5 Lorien is the name of a member of a very old (possibly the oldest) race in the galaxy. Though he can choose to appear humanoid he actually is more of a energy-field. He is very powerful and guides Sheridan through his near-death-dream state.

In LotR Lorien is the name of a member of a very old (possibly the oldest) race on earth. Though they choose to be humanoid, there is no telling how they "really" look. In LotR Lorien is the master of visions and dreams.

Was this name chosen purposefully by J Michael Straczynski? If so, what is it's significance? Or is there a third "Lorien" both Loriens are named after?

This is an out-of-universe-question so obviously I'm not hoping for an in-canon answer. But both authors spoke and wrote extensively about their work so maybe there is some answer out there!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5_influences

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock Now that makes me look kinda stupid, doesn't it? Anyhow: Would you care make an answer out of it?

Comment: Note that the forest of Lorien (a.k.a. Lothlorien) is not explicited to be named after Lorien the Vala.

Comment: @Envite I do get that. Still there is a Vala out there named Lorien and I'd love to know if the B5-Lorien has something to do with it... As it turns out the answer is "no": Straczynski just liked the sound of that name. Pity that!

Comment: If this is about Babylon 5 then the Silmarillion tag should be removed.

Comment: @TylerH, it's about both. Probably the only question in existence that is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**All this speculation is interesting but no one seems to know the answer to this question.**  I even checked out some of his interviews on [TV Legends.org](http://www.emmytvlegends.org/interviews/people/j-michael-straczynski) as well as *JMS Mail* and this was all I found:

> From: J. Michael Straczynski
>   Subject: Lorien
>   To: CIS
>   Date: 11/30/1996 5:57:00 PM
>
> ***I just kinda thought it was a cool sounding name....***
>
> ***jms***

So I would suggest you ask him yourself by posting a question [Here](http://jmsnews.com/forums/) or through his [Twitter](https://twitter.com/straczynski) account.  You may know that JMS is rather approachable about these things.

Comment: This is indeed a correct if disappointing answer. And I'm fairly convinced, he is lying and there is more behind it. But if that's what he said, than that's what he said!

Comment: It is a good question, I really think you should posse the question to him... If he's anything like he was when I met him he'll either make a joke of it (meaning he doesn't want to tell you) or he will spend 10 mins, possibly more, on exactly what he wanted to convey with the name.

Comment: @einer - I don't know about "lying" but there certainly seem to be a considerable number of overlapping names from LOTR in B5. Maybe it was just subconscious.

Comment: @Richard: It wouldn't be the only time such coincidences showed up in *B5*. The Markab are an alien race from Scientology, and Joe Straczynski explicitly stated that if he'd known that before making the show he would have changed the name. Some of this is undoubtedly unconscious; Sheridan falling into the pit is very similar to Gandalf being dragged by the Balrog, but Joe actually got annoyed when asked about the similarity, as he apparently never even considered it. When Joe does something intentionally, such as Elric quoting Gandalf in *The Geometry of Shadows*, he admits it.

Answer (score 8):

The word "Lórien" is a literal translation of the French "le orien(t)" (e.g. that which is like gold). Tolkien uses it to mean "Golden Valley" or "land of gold".

You can see the in-universe and out-of-universe evolution of the name [here](http://thainsbook.net/lothlorien.html#Names);

> **Laurenandë:**
>   *"Laurenande is the Quenya version of Lorinand. The word laurë means "golden light."*
>    <sub>Unfinished Tales: "The History of
>   Galadriel and Celeborn," p. 252-53 note 5</sub>

As far as Babylon 5 is concerned, Showrunner J. Michael Straczynski had a known predilection for 'borrowing names' as well as entire chunks of [plotline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5_influences#The_Lord_of_the_Rings) from LOTR and the Silmarillion to include in his show (q.v. rangers/rangers, Morden/Mordor, Khazad-dûm/Z'ha'dum, Mogath/Morgoth, etc).

That being the case, it seems fairly likely that the name Lorien was chosen as a deliberate homage to one of his own favourite authors.

Comment: 2 downvotes in twenty seconds?

Comment: I preferred iliveunderawesomerock over your's because it is has more sources on the part of Straczynski's intentions that's why I chosen it to be the right one. But I see fail to see a reason to downvote your answer it!

Comment: @Richard I didn't downvote you, but I was downvoted to. So I think the reason is the lack of canon sources and the fact that the answers don't have a direct answer if that makes sense. I personally thought you had a good answer, 1+. And also you appeared to put what you thought mixed into your sources. Instead of having canon and theory separate.

Comment: Despite that the OP *did* say "obviously I'm not hoping for an in-canon answer" so lack of canon sources shouldn't be a reason for a DV.  In fact both this answer and @iliveunderawesomerock's answer were better sourced than the accepted!

Comment: Joe Strazcynski has openly stated that he didn't take anything major from *LotR*. He tended to crib things from the same sources that Tolkien did, not Tolkien himself.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - The similarities are marked. He might not want to admit it (perhaps for copyright issues) but that doesn't mean that they aren't there.

Comment: @Richard: The similarities I sketched in the op don't strike me as coincidental either. And "Lorian" isn't exactly a name you just come up with. Maybe it's a mixture of legal issues and subconscious borrowing on his part.

Comment: @Einer "..isn't exactly a name you just come up with" - yeah, it can be, depending on how you come up with names.  It's not as though it's perfectly obtuse - I usually start with two base words and play with the letters, and Lorien is easy to generate from the name Loren...

Comment: I'm with Izkata on this. The writers of *Star Trek* and Timothy Zahn both came up with the name "Bothan" independetly of each other, describing very different alien species. In my first attempt at short fiction, I wrote a story that happened to be eerily similar to a (far superior) short story that was written in 1991, which I had not read. I also named one country in a fantasy short-story 'Lencia,' which happens to be a country-name from Joe Dever's *Lone Wolf* series. I read that series as a kid, but it didn't click that I'd subconsciously stolen a name. It happens.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - One coincidence is a coincidence. 6 coincidences isn't a coincidence, it's a pattern

Comment: @Richard: I honestly don't find all that many coincidences between *B5* and *LotR*. I think that many of the coincidences tend to be from Tolkien and Straczynski ripping off the same sources, not the latter ripping off the former. We have Elric, who is clearly intentional. We have Lorien, which may have been a subconscious thing on Joe's part. What else is there? There are as many similarities between *LotR* and *Star Wars*, because Tolkien and Lucas were drawing from the same myths. If Kurasawa was around when Tolkien was, the latter would probably have taken from him as well.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - rangers/rangers, Morden/Mordor, Khazad-dûm/Z'ha'dum, Mogath/Morgoth, lorien/lorien, Narn/Narn i Chîn, etc etc. There's more on the wiki but some of them are a bit of a reach/...

Comment: The Rangers and Khazad-dum I'll give you. Morden and Mordor is a hell of a stretch, considering one is a barren wasteland devoid of all hope, and the other is a country in *LotR* (sorry, Ed Wasser). I don't even recall a 'Mogath,' but again, it's a stretch. The Narns are a maybe. But Joe is clearly cribbing things from a variety of sources. The Minbari are an analogue for samurai. Sheridan quotes various Buddhist, American, Japanese, etc., parables. The Centauri are a combination of Rome and Britain. Earthgov is a mix of the Nazis and the Red Scare. Singling out Tolkien seems ridiculous.

Comment: @James Sheridan - Mogath was one of the Centauri gods, god of the underworld in fact (and protector of front doors).

Comment: @JamesSheridan "The writers of Star Trek and Timothy Zahn both came up with the name "Bothan" independetly of each other, describing very different alien species." Zahn didn't come up with the name.  The name was given, without elaboration, in Return of the Jedi ('many Bothans died to bring us this information').  He was the one to explain what a Bothan was though.

Answer (score 5):

[This is all I could find.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5_influences)

> The name Narns might be derived either from C. S. Lewis's The
>   Chronicles of Narnia, or from Tolkien's Narn i Chîn Húrin in The
>   Silmarillion. The name of Tolkien's heart of elvendom, "Lórien" (or
>   "Lothlórien") is given to the first of the First Ones in B5 (see
>   "Lorien"). The name of the Shadows' agent, Mr. Morden, may also
>   reflect Tolkien's Mordor. The similar nature of the names Khazad-dûm
>   and Z'ha'dum has been noted earlier.

This is basically a list of influences used by the Babylon 5. This sort of answers the question. From this source you can see that the Babylon 5 takes a lot from the LoTR and other series.

[From the wikia.](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Lorien)

> The name Lorien bears a striking similarity to "Lothlórien", a forest
>   within the universe of Tolkien's Legendarium. It is also the name of a
>   godlike Vala (more properly named Irmo) in Tolkien's "The
>   Silmarillion".

[This is just definition of the name.](http://www.behindthename.com/submit/name/lorien)